# find and remove duplicates filenames in directory hierarchy

Tags: bash, find

```
#!/bin/sh
LASTBASE=""  
find $1 -type f -print | rev | sort | rev | while read FILE
do
    BASE=$(basename "$FILE")
    if [ "$BASE" = "$LASTBASE" ]; then
        rm "$FILE"
    LASTBASE="$BASE"
done
```

Comment: You could insert the `uniq` command into your script/process...

Comment: I was going to suggest `uniq -d` and an incantation of `sed` to remove every other line.  But not sure how that will fix the white space problem.

Comment: Add `-x` to `#!/bin/sh` to see if it provides any insight?

Comment: @ewwhite uniq isn't useful because i need compare basename not full path

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you pipe the output of `find` into a `while read` loop you can deal with them line by line:

```
find nnn/ -type f -print | rev | sort | rev | while read FILE; do
    ...
done
```

**Edit**: So this method does break if filenames contain double (consecutive) spaces, because `read` actually splits the line up according to `$IFS` and then joins it again when storing the last variable. To address this you could temporarily change `$IFS` to disable splitting:

```
OIFS="$IFS"
IFS=""
find | while read...
IFS="$OIFS"
```

**Edit**: `test` (which is the same as `[`) doesn't have a `==` operator, you just want `=`.

Comment: I don't think that this will work with spaces in filenames as was in the question.

Comment: @mdpc It does work, but does break if there are double spaces.

Comment: yes unfortunately i have more filenames with multiple spaces! :(

Comment: @StefanoCudini See my edit for another solution.

Comment: @mgorven look my edit! im using while, now $BASE have right value but im receive "unexpected operator" in each items

Comment: @StefanoCudini Change `==` to `=`.

Comment: ok I have corrected the == error.
now there are no errors bash, but if the condition comparison is always false!!

Answer (score 2):

I just found this "gem" in an old bash history and it, well, actually works without stumbling over whitespaces in filenames.

### Content-wise Comparison

```
for hash in `find . -exec md5sum {} \; 2>/dev/null | sort | awk '{ print $1 }' | uniq -d`; do 
     find . -exec md5sum {} \; 2>/dev/null | grep $hash | awk '{print $2 }'; 
done;
```

informal:

- First line: traverse the directory tree and calculate the md5sum of all files below, sort this output (format: hash filename), grab the hash column, reduce it to doubled values. (means there are duplicates)
- Second line: for every one of the double-occuring hashes, traverse again and print the filename if the current file has the current hash (means the file is one of multiple)

example output:

```
./aFile
./aFolder/aFile
./1000digitsOfPI
./a/b/c/thousanddigitsofPI
./b File
./bFolder/cFolder/b File
```

Removing is not implemented here because it might be hard to decide which version of the doubled files you want to keep.

---

### Filename-wise Comparison

If you just want to look at filenames and not at contents, it gets even easier:

```
for name in `find . -type f -printf "%f\n" | sort | uniq -d`; do 
    find . -name $name; 
done;
```

*Update: Unfortunately this version is breaking with whitespaces in filenames again.*

Comment: this code is very interesting, but unfortunately I can not run a md5 because the files are very large and server resources is tiny.
In my case I am aware that files with the same name also have the same content
how can I modify your code to do a background check on name only?

Comment: Oh, in that case it's not a wtf-gem anymore, just an ordinary *find*. This textbox doesn't like the long line, I'll edit it into the answer.

Comment: There you go...

Comment: in title i wrote wrote "duplicates filenames" not "duplicates files"
anyway thanks for your code is very useful the same

Comment: I know, all I wanted was to paste some quirky old code that luckily might work for you, even if it does not match your exact request. ;) I have other bad news though. As I'm playing around with it, I see that the filename-comparison suffers from the whitespaces in names again. ARGH. Sorry, don't think it can be done this way.

Comment: view my last edit, im found complete solution(also for white spaces in names) try suggestions of @mgorven

Answer (score 1):

The problem lies in this line of code `for FILE in $FILES; do` - the for loop is assigning the FILE variable based on the white space separator. So if a file has one or more whitespaces then it won't work. Simply change the default IFS from space to new line or tab. If I remember correctly you can set IFS in bash using something like this -

IFS=$'\n'

Comment: sorry but I do not think understand what you mean

Comment: did you try addin `IFS=$'\n'` before the for loop line?